# Calculating sum from a table in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main page and a sub page (frame) one. The frame contains a table that contains numbers in a column. I want to sum up these numbers and get the result from the main page.

Now my problem is just I don't know how to access the `<input>`s in the frame table.

```
<iframe id="iframe_form" name="iframe_form" src="ServicesList_guest_form.php"
frameborder=0 style="width:540px;height:900px;position:absolute;top:710px;" ></iframe>
```

The file `ServicesList_guest_form.php` contains

```
...
<form id="f1" action="save.php" ...>
  <table id="mytable" ... >
     <tr><td><input type="number" name="val1"></td></tr>
     <tr><td><input type="number" name="val2"></td></tr>
     <tr><td><input type="number" name="val3"></td></tr>
     ...
  </table>
</form>
...
```

Thank you for help

Comment: show some code, do you try something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the iframe's document via the following (IE8 or later), see [MDN iframe documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

- $("#iframe_form") gets the jQuery wrapper
- [0] gets the underlying DOM reference
- .contentWindow.document is the document

Like this

```
var innerDoc = $("#iframe_form")[0].contentWindow.document;
```

You can then use jQuery to find your elements

```
console.log($(innerDoc).find("#mytable input"));
```

Summing can then be done by looping

```
var total = 0;
$(innerDoc).find("#mytable input").each(function(index) {
    var value = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (! isNaN(value)) { // just in case field is empty or user garbage
        total += value;
    }
});
console.log(total);
```

Comment: If I have each summed input with class='sum', how should the `find` query be?

Comment: query should be "input.sum"